# Why location doesn't work in app with android 10?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, location, mobile-application

I have an app which streams video and it ensure making photos from another device. It is saving location of device in photo information. It works correctly on older android versions for example 6.0 Unfortunately it doesn't work on android 10 even after updating an app to SDK 29. Do you have any ideas?

When I switch off gps in android 10 phone everything goes well.

Below errors from android studio:

```
    E/i.aoiAgent11EN: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
    I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
    I/FeatureParser: can't find cepheus.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
    E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
    E/Perf: Fail to get file list pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG
        getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        Fail to get file list pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG
        getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

E/AudioPlayer: CPP is working
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve AudioTrack pointer for getPosition()
        at android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_position(Native Method)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition(AudioTrack.java:1699)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.SpeakerOutputStream.getPlayed(SpeakerOutputStream.java:46)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.G711AudioPlayer.writeSilenceBufferIfNeeded(G711AudioPlayer.java:136)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.G711AudioPlayer.run(G711AudioPlayer.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
I/chatty: uid=10262(pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG) identical 18 lines
E/AudioPlayer: CPP is working
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve AudioTrack pointer for getPosition()
        at android.media.AudioTrack.native_get_position(Native Method)
        at android.media.AudioTrack.getPlaybackHeadPosition(AudioTrack.java:1699)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.SpeakerOutputStream.getPlayed(SpeakerOutputStream.java:46)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.G711AudioPlayer.writeSilenceBufferIfNeeded(G711AudioPlayer.java:136)
        at pl.biz.aoi.aoiAgent11ENG.media.in.audio.player.G711AudioPlayer.run(G711AudioPlayer.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Same issue here, app crashes at every run because of this.

Comment: I am also facing same issue